# Determine whether the given set as follows is linearly independent or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $V=\mathcal{F}[0,1]$ be a vector space of functions defined on $[0,1]$ over $\Bbb R$.
Let $S = \left\{\frac{1}{x^2-4},\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2},\frac{1}{x^2-x-2}\right\} \subset V$.
Determine whether $S$ is linearly independent or not.

**Attempt:**
For the simplify, write $f_1 = \frac{1}{x^2-4},f_2 = \frac{1}{x^2+3x+2},$ and $f_3=\frac{1}{x^2-x-2}$.
Then, $S=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$.

The linear independence or dependence of these vectors is determined by whether the vector equation
\begin{equation*}
k_1f_1+k_2f_2+k_3f_3=0 \ldots (1)
\end{equation*}
can be satisfied with coefficients that are not all zero. To see whether this is so, let us rewrite $(1)$ in its function form
\begin{equation*}
\frac{k_1}{x^2-4} + \frac{k_2}{x^2+3x+2} + \frac{k_3}{x^2-x-2} = 0 \ldots (2)
\end{equation*}
or, equivalently, as
\begin{align*}
\frac{k_1(x+1) + k_2(x-2) + k_3(x+2)}{(x+2)(x+1)(x-2)} &= 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{x(k_1+k_2+k_3) + (k_1-2k_2+2k_3)}{(x+2)(x+1)(x-2)} &= 0.
\end{align*}
Since this equation must be satisfied by all $x \in [0,1]$, then each coefficient must be zero.
Thus, the linear dependence or independence of the given functions in $S$ hinges on whether the following linear system has a nontrivial solution:
\begin{align*}
k_1+k_2+k_3 &= 0 \\
k_1 - 2k_2 + 2k_3 &= 0 \ \ \ \ldots (t) \\
0k_1 + 0k_2 + 0k_3 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
By direct calculation, we get $(k_1,k_2,k_3) = (-4t,t,3t)$ with $t \in \Bbb R$. That is, the solution is depend on $t$ and the system $(t)$ has nontrivial solutions.

Hence, $S$ is linearly dependent. Alternatively, we can show that $(t)$ has nontrivial solutions
by showing that the coefficients matrix has determinant zero, and thus, $S$ is linearly dependent.

Am I true?

Comment: I think, your approach is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach is correct. Note that solving the system $(t)$ is a waste of time, since it is a homogeneous system of $2$ linear equations with $3$ variables. *Any* homogeneous system of linear equations with more variables than equations has nontrivial solutions.

---

Another approach would be to note that$$\frac1{x^2-4}=\frac{1/4}{x-2}+\frac{-1/4}{x+2},$$that$$\frac1{x^2+3x+2}=\frac1{x+1}+\frac{-1}{x+2},$$and that$$\frac1{x^2-x-2}=\frac{1/3}{x-2}+\frac{-1/3}{x+1}.$$So, each of your rational fractions belongs to$$\left\{\frac a{x-2}+\frac b{x+1}+\frac c{x+2}\,\middle|\,a+b+c=0\,\right\}$$whose dimension is at most $2$ (actually, it is equal to $2$, but that's not important) and therefore they cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Oh I see, I forgot that fact. Thanks Sir!